# php one line echo string1 or string2

Tags: php, html, string, random, echo

here's the current code

```
<a href="<?='http://help.mysite.com/' or 'http://help.mysite.net/';?>">Help</a>
```

how can I print the server url with two choice?

googled but nothing seen!

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: Which one do you want to echo???

Comment: Post your complete code here. for which purpose you want to use this???

Comment: Like `<?=rand(0,1)?'http://help.mysite.com/':'http://help.mysite.net/'?>`??

Comment: That was meant to be a joke. *Why so serious @jkjk?*

Answer (score 0):

There was earlier similar post, you can check that:

[Checking a Url in Jquery/Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4301968/checking-a-url-in-jquery-javascript)

Here an ajax call is made to URLs, if the URL doesn't exist then the function related to error block is called where you can call function which would use the next available URL and try the ajax call again.

You can loop like this until you don't have any URL or one of the URL is found, during which function associated with success block will be called.