# How to stop $.getScript() error message?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, getscript

I simply call `$.getSCript(location.href)` and it gets the script properly, however if the file is not there (and that is what I am planning to do a lot) it prints an error `GET (url) 500 (Internal Server Error)`

How to prevent that from happening? How to get rid of error message?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried including an empty fail event?

```
$.getScript(SOME_LOCATION)
.done(function(script, textStatus) {
  // Whatever...
})
.fail(function(jqxhr, settings, exception) {
  // Just leave this empty
});
```

Alternatively, you can check if the URL is valid before using getScript, as described in the answer here: 
[Checking a Url in Jquery/Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4301968/checking-a-url-in-jquery-javascript)

Comment: I did try empty `.fail()` and it didn't work. I also cannot use checking url, because calling on location.href in `$.ajax({url:location.href})` is not the same as in `$.getScript(location.href)` so I would have to worry about stripping down get parameters