# Cancel event in AJAX response fire from misc/AJAX.js

Tags: ajax, events

How can I override Drupal.ajax written in misc/ajax.js?

I need to check URL existence before firing an AJAX call.

Is there any other way/better way to achieve that without overriding this js?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about Drupal.ajax but [this Jquery Method](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxsend/) is the way to go:
`$(document).ajaxSend(function(event, jqxhr, settings){
    if ( settings.url == "some urls" ) {//checks if related url should be checked or not.
      //Do Something like`[This url checking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4301968/checking-a-url-in-jquery-javascript)`or what ever you want.
      if(!UrlExists(settings.url)){
        jqxhr.abort();
      }
    }
});`

Be careful, This method is a global ajax event -- so this effectively can filter all ajax requests.