# JQuery check if url exist No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to check if url exist using JQuery and following

[Checking a Url in Jquery/Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4301968/checking-a-url-in-jquery-javascript)

However I am getting

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://10.16.20.22:8080/xxx. No 'Access-Control-Allow-
Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access.

My question is how can I check if url exist?

Comment: What is the question ?

Comment: My question is how can I check if url exist?

Comment: Have you the control of `http://10.16.20.22:8080/xxx` ?

Comment: You can try to create iframe than check, is there any content

Comment: possible duplicate of ["No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource)

Comment: If you don't have control of the remote system, one solution would be to setup a "proxy" script on your own webserver (using the server side language of your choice). This proxy will check the existence of the remote system and report the result to your current Javascript (which in turn will not check the remote system but the proxy ... with the remote URL as a parameter)

Answer (score 1):

Here `dataType: jsonp` for `cross-domain request`, that means request to different domain where `dataType: json` for same domain-same origin request.

```
function urlExists(url, successCallBack) {
  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    dataType: "jsonp",
    statusCode: {
      200: function(response) {
        console.log('status 200');
        successCallBack();
      },
      404: function(response) {
        console.log('status  404 ');
      }
    }
  });
}
urlExists("http://google.com", function() {
  console.log('side exists so I got executed');
});
```

Codepen link
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/waEVmv